# Microsoft Surface: "Read" the tag value of an IdentityTag

Tags: wpf, tags, pixelsense

is it possible to read the value of an IdentityTag if you place it on the TagVisualizer, without having initalized it before?

I would like to use the tags for registering a new object on the Surface but having all the "free" IdentityTags in a Collection for initalizing them all... There must be a better way to do in I think.

But the TagVisualizer doesn't seem to do anything when you put a tag on it that it doesn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'll need to start by setting up your TagVisualizer with a [TagVisualizationDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.controls.tagvisualizationdefinition(Surface.10).aspx) with a [Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.controls.tagvisualizationdefinition.matches(v=Surface.10).aspx) method that always returns true.

Comment: That seems to be the right answer, but I don't know where to put this Matches-method into.

Comment: subclass TagVisualizationDefinition